# Splitting String in python and convert to json

Tags: python, json, string

I'm having a string like this :

```
{'4': {1, 2}, '2': {1, 2}, '0': {1, 2}}["eq('2', '0')", "eq('2', '4')", "eq('0','4')"]
```

And I only need everything before ["eq('2'....  so I only need to save {'4': {1, 2}, '2': {1, 2}, '0': {1, 2}}
I cannot use index because the length can be different everytime so I have to somehow check for "[". Is there anyway in python to do this and then convert the result into json? I'm new to python so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: "Is there anyway in python to do this" yes there is. [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) is your friend. "and then convert the result into json" Yep, [there's a whole module for json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: @AdamSmith: Except that the value given can't be directly encoded as JSON because it contains sets. Once you decide how you want to wrap the sets up in something JSON does include, it's not that hard, but until then it's impossible.

Comment: Why do you have two JSON serializations concatenated together? Regardless, any solution that doesn't involve a parser will be brittle because you're not tracking how deep you are in the object tree.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: They're not valid JSON serializations; they're probably Python `repr`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is actually this specific, it's pretty easy: just split on the `[`, because there are no `[` parts inside the `{…}`. So:

```
>>> s = """{'4': {1, 2}, '2': {1, 2}, '0': {1, 2}}["eq('2', '0')", "eq('2', '4')", "eq('0','4')"]"""
>>> sd, _, sl = s.partition('[')
>>> sl = '[' + sl
```

Now, presumably you don't want to convert the *string* to JSON, but the `dict` that the string *represents*. To do that, you have to `eval` it. Because you've got nothing but displays full of literals, you can use the safe `ast.literal_eval` function to do that. So:

```
>>> import ast
>>> d = ast.literal_eval(sd)
>>> sd
"{'4': {1, 2}, '2': {1, 2}, '0': {1, 2}}"
>>> d
{'2': {1, 2}, '4': {1, 2}, '0': {1, 2}}
```

However, you still can't JSON-ify that, because `{1, 2}` is a set, and JSON doesn't do sets. You have to decide what you want to convert that into. An array? A dict with `None` values? Something else?

---

To turn all of the sets into lists (which can be rendered as JSON arrays), you have two choices.

The first is to subclass the `JSONEncoder`. There's a perfect example right near the top of [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) that does the same thing for encoding `complex` values as 2-element lists, which you should be able to adapt to your purposes easily: just change the `complex` to `set`, and the `[o.real, o.imag]` to `list(o)`.

The second is to preprocess things. As with the initial parsing, how easy this is depends on how rigid your format is. If all of the top-level values of the dict are sets, and nothing else is a set, it's just `{k: list(v) for k, v in sd.items()}`. If, on the other hand, you have an arbitrary dict that recursively contains sets along with strings, numbers, dicts, and lists, then you'll probably want to write a recursive function to transform it.

---

Meanwhile… where did you get this data from? My guess is that you're got some *other* part of your code that's just printing out a dict (or `f.write`-ing a `str()` of a dict…) followed by a list. If so, instead of trying to recover that data later, you should change your code to write JSON (or something else parseable) in the first place.

---

If your format were a little bit less friendly—if the dict could have lists inside it—you'd need to do something fancier. For example, you could count up open braces minus close braces and keep going until you get back to 0, and that's the dict.

Comment: thanks for your help, let's say I want to change the {1,2} to array [1,2]. I'm sending this data to javascript so I need to iterate every item in the json object and read it's array

Comment: @HiradRoshandel: Edited the answer to explain.